# Erro ao pegar nome da Fase - IONIC

Tags: ionic, sqlite, mobile

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo um app no Ionic, criei a função para verificar a resposta correta, porém na linha que teria que aparecer a área sendo exibida (mensagem+='

'+this.processo.NOME_AREA.toLowerCase()+'

'). Cria-se um alert escrito undefined. Verifiquei e minha consulta no provider esta funcionando retornando o nome da area.

Meu Component:

import { HomePage } from './../home/home';
import { CalculosProvider } from './../../providers/calculos/calculos';
import { AreaProvider } from './../../providers/area/area';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ToastController, ModalController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProcessoProvider } from '../../providers/processo/processo';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-area',
  templateUrl: 'area.html',
})
export class AreaPage {

public codigoAreaEscolhida: number;
  public acertos: number;
  public tentativas: number;
  public erros: number;

//no android
  public areas: any[];

//no computador
  /*
  public areas = [
    {
      NOME: "AREA 1",
      CODIGO_AREA: 1
    },

```
{
  NOME: "AREA 2",
  CODIGO_AREA: 2
},

{
  NOME: "AREA 3",
  CODIGO_AREA: 3
}
```

];
*/

//no android

public processo = {
    NOME: "",
    CODIGO_PROCESSO: "",
    CODIGO_AREA: 0,
    NOME_AREA: ""
  };

//no computador
  /*
    public processo = {
      NOME: "PROCESSO DE TRANSIÇÃO E TÉRMINO DE COMPONENTES PARA O TCC",
      CODIGO_PROCESSO: 1,
      CODIGO_AREA: 2,
      NOME_AREA:"INCIAÇÃO"
    };
  */

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public modalCtrl : ModalController,public alertCtrl:AlertController,
     private toast: ToastController, private areaProvider: AreaProvider, private calculosProvider: CalculosProvider,
      private processoProvider: ProcessoProvider) {

```
this.acertos = 0;
this.tentativas = 0;
this.erros = 0;
this.refresh();
```

}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    let elem = document.querySelector(".tabbar");
    if (elem != null) {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

presentConfirm() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Saindo da Aplicação',
      message: 'Tem certeza que deseja sair?  ',

```
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'CANCELAR',
      role: 'CANCELAR',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'SIM',
      handler: () => {
        //this.navCtrl.pop(HomePage);
        //this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);

      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
```

}

refresh() {

```
// no android
this.getAreas();
this.getProcessoAleatorio();
```

}

getAreas() {
    this.areaProvider.getAll()
      .then((result: any[]) => {
        this.areas = result;
        //this.toast.create({ message: "Areas carregadas com sucesso.", duration: 1000, position: 'botton' }).present();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        //this.toast.create({ message: 'Erro ao carregar as areas.', duration: 1000, position: 'botton' }).present();
      });

}

getProcessoAleatorio() {
    let processoAleatorio = this.calculosProvider.getRandomInt(1, 48);

```
this.processoProvider.getByIdArea(processoAleatorio)
  .then((result: any) => {
    this.processo.NOME = result.NOME;
    this.processo.CODIGO_PROCESSO = processoAleatorio;
    this.processo.CODIGO_AREA = result.CODIGO_AREA;
    this.processo.NOME_AREA = result.NOME_AREA;
    //this.toast.create({ message: "Processo carregado", duration: 1000, position: 'bottom' }).present();
  })
```

}

enviar() {

```
if (this.processo.CODIGO_AREA == this.codigoAreaEscolhida) {

  //this.toast.create({ message: 'Parabéns, você acertou', duration: 900, position: 'bottom' }).present();
  this.acertos++;

} else {
  //this.showErrou();
  this.erros++;
  //this.toast.create({ message: `Você errou! A área correta é :  ${this.processo.NOME_AREA}`,
   //duration:2500, position: 'botton' }).present();
   this.showErrou();
}
this.tentativas++;
this.refresh();
```

}

showErrou() {
    let mensagem= 'A resposta esta incorreta';
    mensagem+='

'+this.processo.NOME_AREA.toLowerCase()+'

';

```
mensagem+="</ul>"

let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: '<font color="red">Resposta Errada!</font>',
  subTitle: mensagem,
  buttons: ['CONTINUAR']
});
alert.present();
```

}

areaEscolhida(codigoArea: number) {
    this.codigoAreaEscolhida = codigoArea;
    console.log(this.codigoAreaEscolhida);
  }

}

Meu provider:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLiteObject} from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { DatabaseProvider} from '../database/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProcessoProvider {

constructor(private databaseProvider:DatabaseProvider) {
    console.log('Hello ProcessoProvider Provider');
  }

public getById(id:number){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      //let sql = 'select p.*, f.nome as NOME_FASE from processo p, fase f where p.codigo_processo = ? and p.codigo_fase = f.codigo_fase';
        let sql='select p.*, f.nome as NOME_FASE, a.nome as NOME_AREA from processo p, fase f, area a where p.codigo_processo = ? and p.codigo_fase = f.codigo_fase and p.codigo_area = a.codigo_area';
      let data = [id];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let item = data.rows.item(0);
            return item;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getAll(){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.* from processo p where p.codigo_processo';
      let data = [];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let processos:any[] = [];
            for (var i=0;iconsole.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByIdArea(id:number){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.*, a.nome as NOME_AREA from processo p, area a where p.codigo_processo = ? and a.codigo_area = p.codigo_area';
      let data = [id];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let item = data.rows.item(0);
            return item;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByNotArea(codigo_area){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.* from processo p where p.codigo_area <> ?';
      let data = [codigo_area];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let processos:any[] = [];
            for (var i=0;iconsole.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByArea(id:number){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.* from processo p where p.codigo_area = ?';
      let data = [id];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let processos:any[] = [];
            for (var i=0;iconsole.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByIdFase(id:number){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.*, a.nome as NOME_FASE from processo p, fase a where p.codigo_processo = ? and a.codigo_fase = p.codigo_fase';
      let data = [id];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let item = data.rows.item(0);
            return item;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
        .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByFase(id:number){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.* from processo p where p.codigo_fase = ?';
      let data = [id];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let processos:any[] = [];
            for (var i=0;iconsole.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

public getByNotFase(codigo_fase){
    return this.databaseProvider.getDB()
    .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
      let sql = 'select p.* from processo p where p.codigo_fase <> ?';
      let data = [codigo_fase];
      return db.executeSql(sql,data)
        .then((data:any) => {
          if(data.rows.length > 0){
            let processos:any[] = [];
            for (var i=0;iconsole.error(e));
    })
    .catch((e)=>console.error(e));
  }

}